# Scroll datetimepicker jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created this form:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <fieldset>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label>Customer:</label>
            <input class='form-control' placeholder='' name='customer' type='text' readonly value='<?php echo $customerInfo['name'] . ' ' . $customerInfo['surname'];?>'>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label>Assignment:</label>
            <input class='form-control' placeholder='' name='assignment' type='text' readonly value='<?php echo $assignment['description'];?>'>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label>Current state:</label>
            <input class='form-control' placeholder='' name='assignment' type='text' readonly value='<?php echo $state['name'];?>'>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>New state:</label>
            <select name="selectValue" class="form-control" id="selectState">
                <?php
                    foreach($allStates as $state){
                        $id = $state['id'];
                        $code = $state['code'];
                        $name = $state['name'];
                        echo "<option value=$id>$code - $name</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class='form-control' id="datetimepicker" type="text">
    </div>
    <input class='btn btn-info btn-sm' name='requestClosing' type='submit' value='Update assignment'>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

With this as result:

[image: Form]

But when I want to select a date and scroll down the page. The datetimepicker disappears. This way it is not possible to select a date.

Could anyone help me out fixing this issue?

Comment: You could add extra height to the parent when the focus is in that text field.

Comment: Or have it at the top, by using `widgetPositioning` api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

use option [closeOnWithoutClick](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#closeOnWithoutClick).set `closeOnWithoutClick:false`,also set `closeOnDateSelect:true` to close datetimepicker after selecting date.

```
$("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
    closeOnDateSelect:true,
    closeOnWithoutClick:false
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0eapLjyj/)